# How to read Spring properties from file by section

Tags: spring

Is it possible to get properties from a property file that divides the properties in sections? If so, how?

Ex.
props.properties

```
[section1]
a=1
b=2
c=3

[section2]
a=4
b=5
c=6
```

How can 'section1' be selecting using spring?  In the code, how can one read property 'a' from section1.  Is there anything that allows the programmer to select section1 and then property a?

Edit: Also note that property name in both sections are the same.  section1 has property 'a' and section2 also has a property 'a'.

Edit 2: What I am looking for is a way to create map of maps.  For example, properties.get("section1").get("a") should return 1 and properties.get("section2").get("a") should return 4.  The data that I am using contains countries and provinces. So for "country 1", there are provinces denoted by numbers: 1=AL, 2=AK, etc; for "country 2", there are also provinces denoted by number: 1=AB, 2=BC, etc.  I want to be able to get provence based on country: properties.get("country 1").get("1") returns AL, and properties.get("country 2").get("1") returns AB.  Using a prefix will not allow me to select a country dynamically, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, if you prefix all properties with the section name, e.g.

```
section1.a=1
section1.b=2


...
section2.a=4
section2.b=5
```

And then inject the properties with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="section1")`

Comment: Will this allow me to switch between section2 and section1 in the same class file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into using **YAML** instead of Properties for your Spring configuration:

[Spring Documentation - Using YAML instead of Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This builds on the ides that @jny suggested. reduced the amount of copy/pasting needed to add properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Profiles in Spring and have a different property file for each enviroment. Something like

**application-dev.properties**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
a=4
b=5
c=6
```

Here there are two examples of using properties with enviroments

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: Thanks for your response @reos.  I wanted to keep the properties in the same file since both of the 'sections' will be needed both all environments.